# User automatically logged out by system after changing store

Tags: customer, multistore, login, customer-account, websites

I have a multi-store web site for different cities. Users have an option to select their city and buy products available in that particular city. They have to register for buying products.

For sharing the information of customer data with all store, I configured the

`System->Configuration->Customer Configuration->Account Sharing Option->Share Customer Account->Global`

by doing this setting user can log in using their single login credential for any city, even if they register from there selected city. For example, if user X register after selecting Y city he/she can log in A city using the same login id and password successfully.

Now problem came when user login in the website after selecting any city and after this if user change city then they have to do login process again for that next selected city. For ex. if I select X city and log in and then if I select Y city I automatically logged out and again I have to log in for Y  city.

See the images for problem reference -
[image: Image 1 shows user selected city and logged IN]

[image: Image 2 shows after changing the city user automatically logged OUT]

How can I fix this problem? For better understanding, you may visit [RoyalCart](http://www.myroyalcart.com)

Any help will be appreciable. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a cookie problem:
Make sure, that your cookie path is empty, so every store is allowed to read the session cookie, so every store knows which customer it is.

If this doesn't, dig into the code (xdebug is your friend) and check wether `\Mage_Customer_Model_Session::logout` is called and if yes, why.